# Why the Javascript files imported by a Twig template in a Symfony2 application are renamed?

Tags: javascript, symfony, tinymce, twig, assetic

I need to use the TinyMCE javascript library in a Symfony2 project. Well, I'm following the [for dummies tutorial](http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/%22For_Dummies%22) for using this library. Hence, since I'm using the Symfony2 framework, I saved the library into my bundle *Resouces/public/js* and then I imported the script through Assetic in my Twig template. Here follows the code:

```
{% block javascripts %}
    {{ parent() }}
    {% javascripts 
        '@AcmeTestBundle/Resources/public/js/tiny_mce/tiny_mce.js' 
    %}
    <script src="{{ asset_url }}" type="text/javascript"></script>
    {% endjavascripts %}
    <script type="text/javascript" >
        tinyMCE.init({
            mode : "textareas",
            theme : "simple"
        });
    </script >            
{% endblock %}
```

Then, when I render the template I see that no textarea in my form is working as expected with the TinyMCE library. 
Any idea? I don't know if it helps, but I've got a look at the HTML source code, and I saw that the Assetic imported the library as folloows:

```
<script src="/Acme/web/app_dev.php/js/0540f06_tiny_mce_1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Why the original path and JS file have been renamed?

Comment: Because you use assetic for the asset management a few things might not work as expected. What does Firebug day?

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand! Can you explain it more precisely?

Comment: Okay - I recommend using the Firefox plugin "Firebug" for debugging what went wrong. If you don't want this - do not use assetic in the Twig template and try putting TinyMCE in your "public" folder in your base application path.

Comment: Well, I'm currently trying to not use Assetic, i.e. I use `<script src="{{ asset('js/tiny_mce/tiny_mce.js') }}" type="text/javascript"></script>` but Symfony is not capable of rendering the page. The browser report the following error "**The connection was reset**". The only way to render a page is by using Assetic!

Comment: Have you cleared the symfony cache?

Comment: For sure! I did also a reboot! The browser fails only if I don't use Assetic! However, if I use Assetic the Javascripts doesn't work!

Comment: Well, now it is working without Assetic. First, I installed all the resources in public with `php app/console assets:install web/` then I used the following code: `<script src="{{ asset('bundles/acmetest/js/tiny_mce/tiny_mce.js') }}" type="text/javascript"></script>`. In my mind, the right place for this Js was not inside a specific bundle! I have to check it again!

Answer (score 1):

The [`output`](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/assetic/asset_management.html#controlling-the-url-used) option allows you to control the resulting location of an asset.

Comment: I know that, but I suppose here that there is something more complicated to handle. I guess that Assetic works fine if you have to load a single JavaScript file that does not point to other JavaScripts. Unfortunately, this is the case of the **tiny_mce** library, which is made of subdirectories full of JavaScripts. Another observation: maybe this is a problem of the DEV environment, but also with the `output` option all the files are not rendered as expected. For instance, such number is added to the filename.